# error during writing folders names into a text file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding, python-unicode

I'm setting up a script that allows me to have a text file with all the names of songs, solders and subfolders that I have in my main music folder.

I've coded it this way

```
import os
folderNames=[]
subFolders=[]
filenames=[]
for folder_names, subfolder_names, file_names in 
    os.walk(r'C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\Musica'):
    folderNames.append(folder_names)
    openFolderNames=open('allFolders.txt', 'w')
    openFolderNames.write(str(folderNames))

    for subfolder_name in subfolder_names:
        subFolders.append(subfolder_name)
        opensubfolders=open('allSubfolders.txt', 'w')
        opensubfolders.write(str(subFolders))
    for file_name in file_names:
        filenames.append(file_name)
        openfilenames=open('filenames.txt', 'w')
        openfilenames.write(str(filenames))
print('Done!!!')
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\My Python Programs\Chapter9\walkingDirectoryTree\walkingDirectoryTree.py", line 17, 
in <module> openfilenames.write(str(filenames))
File "C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0107' in 
position 7974: character maps to <undefined>
```

I think I kinda need to append raw strings, but I checked on the internet and I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python [uses the default codepage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) when writing to disk on Windows - this appears to be cp1252 in your case.  Some of the paths or filenames being collected contain characters that cannot be encoded as cp1252, hence the error.

Possible solutions are:

- encode the data as utf-8 when writing to disk: `open('allFolders.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')` (remember to open the files with UTF-8 when reading from them)
- set the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable to UTF-8 when running your program
- set the  [PYTHONUTF8](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUTF8) environment variable when running your program